# How to export Mongo-database using Docker?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, export

I use "mongoDB" image in docker-container. 
When I run command for export DB to csv:

```
docker exec -i 418f46e5595d  mongoexport --db saveInfo --collection infoobjects --type=csv --fields _id,postLink,postTitle,contactPhone --out ./info.csv
```

File saved in folder where container is working. How can I save it on my machine?

Comment: I think you can use [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/). 
Or start container with mounted volume https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Answer (score 5):

remove the `--out` option so it will export to `stdout` and redirect output to a file, something like this:

```
docker exec -i 418f46e5595d  mongoexport --db saveInfo --collection infoobjects --type=csv --fields _id,postLink,postTitle,contactPhone | gzip > info.csv
```

You might want to redirect error messages to a different stream, so:

```
docker exec -i 418f46e5595d  mongoexport --db saveInfo --collection infoobjects --type=csv --fields _id,postLink,postTitle,contactPhone 2>/tmp/mongoexport.err | gzip > info.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

My decision:
1) export
`docker exec -i 418f46e5595d  mongoexport --db saveInfo --collection infoobjects --type=csv --fields _id,postLink,postTitle,contactPhone --out
 ./info.csv`
2)copy to my machine
 
`docker cp webspider_mongo_1:/data/info.csv .`

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions are great, but just adding an alternative also:

**docker-compose.yml** - mount to local folder ./mongodb_data:/data/db

```
services:
  mongo1:
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb_data:/data/db
```

**export to relative mongo path** - /data/db/info.csv - Will automatically populate into local folder - ./mongodb_data/info.csv

```
docker exec -i 418f46e5595d  mongoexport --db saveInfo --collection infoobjects --type=csv --fields _id,postLink,postTitle,contactPhone --out "/data/db/info.csv";
```