# How to export MONGODB collection into json or csv format , the mongodb is inside a docker container

Tags: python, mongodb

I have an application inside a docker container which uses mongodb.
There is a particular db called "device" and it has an collection called "inventory" , I want all of this collection into a json or csv file , so that i can export the data into splunk and analyze.

When i try to get information for one device id , it works and i am redirecting it to a file

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker exec -it ss2-$HOSTNAME mongo device -u marco -p <pasword> --authenticationDatabase admin  --eval 'printjson(db.inventory.findOne({"host_ip": "1.1.1.1"}))' --quiet >> /tmp/json.txt
```

But i want all the collection to be displayed and to be redirected /tmp/json.txt

I did try

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker exec -it ss2-$HOSTNAME mongo device -u marco -p <pasword> --authenticationDatabase admin  --eval 'printjson(db.inventory.find( {} ))' --quiet >> /tmp/json.txt
```

This displays all the collection data when i run inside the container , but when i run outside i dont see any data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export Mongo-database using Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892753/how-to-export-mongo-database-using-docker)

Comment: I don't think that `printjson` is able to handle a [cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) when you start returning more than a couple of items. Like the question that M. R. pointed to shows, `mongoexport` is going to be the correct tool for this job.

Comment: can u help me how to change this guy into mongoexport ,i tried and failed a lot

```sudo /usr/local/bin/docker exec -it ss2-$HOSTNAME mongo device -u marco -p <pasword> --authenticationDatabase admin  --eval 'printjson(db.inventory.find( {} ))' --quiet >> /tmp/json.txt```

Comment: I THink i figured it out now the error is
assertion: 9998 you need to specify fields

What if i want all fields ?

Comment: I figured it out thank you !!!!